# Remove special character from input form

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to JavaScript and already go through similar questions. I create an input mask for phone number where it has the region code in the form. However, it saves in the database together with the region code. How can I remove special character from an input form? For example:

> (+60)123456789 --> 0123456789

I have this block of code where the input form goes:

```
<div className="mt-4">
   <InputMaskComponent
      id="company_phone_no"
      mask="+(60)999999999999"
      label="Company Phone Number"
      value={(formState.company_phone_no || '').replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, '')}
      variant="standard"
      onChange={handleChange}
   >
   </InputMaskComponent>
</div>
```

I try to use the replace() but still cannot managed to get it right. I already have this mask.js component:

```
export default function InputMaskComponent({id,mask,value,onChange,label,variant}) {
    return (
      <InputMask 
        id={id}
        name={id}
        mask={mask}
        maskChar=""
        value={value} 
        onChange={onChange}
        >
        {()=> <TextField fullWidth id={id} name={id} label={label} variant={variant} />}
      </InputMask>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your regex should be able to remove the special characters. You wanted to remove special characters, but why the "6" is removed as well?

Comment: @Alexzhang I go through the internet and found this regex replace(/\D+/g, '') . However, I still can't manage to strip only the number from the mask. I believe I messed up the placement of the replace() since I only try and error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your regular expression /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g is designed to match non-alphanumeric characters and spaces, but it doesn't include the plus sign (+) in the allowed characters. To remove the + character, need to update the regular expression -

```
value={(formState.company_phone_no || '').replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')}
```

This regular expression (/[^0-9]/g) matches any character that is not a digit (0-9) and removes it. This will include the plus sign in the set of characters to be removed.